# Unable to use Systemd to start my Docker container

Tags: command-line, server, scripts, systemd, docker

I have a very specific issue with running a Docker container on boot using systemd.

The container starts and stops successfully with the following scripts:

start-container.sh

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sleep 5
docker start container_name
```

stop-container.sh

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sleep 5
docker stop container_name
```

However, when I configure the following service using systemd, it does not run successfully:

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Container
After=network.target
After=systemd-user-sessions.service
After=network-online.target
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=root
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/seed/scripts/start-container.sh
ExecStop=/home/seed/scripts/stop-container.sh
TimeoutSec=60
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30
StartLimitInterval=350
StartLimitBurst=10

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: Update: I followed this https://mehmandarov.com/start-docker-containers-automatically/ too and updated the service file to require and run after docker.service.

But this does not work either!

Answer (score 1):

Absolute paths are key to success in shell scripting.

Why not make it without home directory scripts (that is not good practise in services) :

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Container
After=network.target
After=systemd-user-sessions.service
After=network-online.target
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=root
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker start -a container_name
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop -t 5 container_name
TimeoutSec=60
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30
StartLimitInterval=350
StartLimitBurst=10

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Happy dockering!